# Add multiple parent keys to json array

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file, example.json:

```
[
  [
    "126",
    1522767000
  ],
  [
    "122",
    1522859400
  ],
  [
    "126",
    1523348520
  ]
]
```

...and would like to add multiple parent items with the desired output:

```
{
  "target": "Systolic",
  "datapoints": [
    [
      "126",
      1522767000
    ],
    [
      "122",
      1522859400
    ],
    [
      "126",
      1523348520
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm having trouble, attempting things like:

`cat example.json | jq -s '{target:.[]}'`, which adds the one key but not understanding how to add a value to the `target` and another key `datapoints`.

Comment: decided also to help you with some of your older queries. This one could be achieved with _jtc_ like this: **`jtc -T'{"target": "Systolic", "datapoints": {{}}}' -f example.json`** - it will apply update right into your source `example.json`, so that you don't have to save/redirect the output (PS. I'm a developer of the `jtc` tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With straightforward **`jq`** expression:

```
jq '{target: "Systolic", datapoints: .}' example.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "target": "Systolic",
  "datapoints": [
    [
      "126",
      1522767000
    ],
    [
      "122",
      1522859400
    ],
    [
      "126",
      1523348520
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I had attempted to use the `map` function, didn't realize it was so literal. Good lesson, thank you.